# How to display very large Metal-based textures in an NSScrollView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, metal, core-image, nsscrollview

I have a program that displays an image inside an `NSScrollView`. I'm using Metal to render the image, so the `NSClipView`'s `documentView` is a `MTKView`. I support the ability to zoom in/out of the image. The last steps of my render pipeline wrap my Metal texture into a `CIImage` where I apply the `CIAffineTransform` filter to do the scaling. I render the image in `drawRect` into a drawable like this:

```c
CIImage *image = ...;
CIRenderDestination *renderDest = [[CIRenderDestination alloc] initWithWidth:image.extent.size.width
                                                                      height:image.extent.size.height
                                                                 pixelFormat:self.colorPixelFormat
                                                               commandBuffer:commandBuffer
                                                          mtlTextureProvider:^id<MTLTexture> _Nonnull{
    return drawable.texture;
}];

[self.ciContext startTaskToRender:image
                    toDestination:renderDest
                            error:&error];
```

When the document view size changes I update the view's `drawableSize` property. This works great and the scrolling and scroll bars work as expected. The problem is when the magnification factor gets too large the drawable's underlying texture exceeds the GPU memory:

```
validateTextureDimensions, line 1081: error 'MTLTextureDescriptor has width (18798) greater than the maximum allowed size of 16384.'
validateTextureDimensions:1081: failed assertion `MTLTextureDescriptor has width (18798) greater than the maximum allowed size of 16384.'
```

so drawing a cropped image into part of the drawable won't work (not that I know how to do that from a `CIImage`). This happens even if I don't draw any image into the view (i.e. just set the expected drawable size) which suggests the `MTKView`'s drawable is the problem. Of course, I don't need to draw the full image; just the part that's visible in the clip view. I could restrict the `drawableSize`/document view, but then I'd have to effectively implement scrolling manually and lose the scroll bars.

What is the best path for a standard scroll view while still displaying extremely large images? Alternately, is there a path to use something like `CATiledLayer` with Metal?

Comment: I'm still at the amateur level with Metal, but it seems like it'd be simpler to just eliminate the middleman (CIImage) and do the Metal drawing yourself.  You'd just draw two triangles to cover the rectangular area of the entire (unclipped) texture, and your fragment shader would just sample from your texture.  That way the scaling would all happen on the GPU.  Given that you already have a MTLTexture and an MTKView, this seems like it would be quite straightforward (once you wrap your head around the details of Metal's rendering architecture).

Comment: I do want to utilize the Core Image filters, but the bigger issue is that I still want the NSScroll functionality (system scrolling and scrollbars).

Comment: It seems to me that with the approach I suggest you'd get the standard NSScroll functionality for free.  The MTKView would be the full size of your zoomed-in texture, and would be embedded inside the scroll view.  The Metal drawing of your texture would be automatically translated and clipped, I think, if you wrote the code right.  But yes, if you want to use CI filters, then CI obviously has to be involved.  I do wonder, though: if you want CI to transform your image, then do you need to involve Metal at all?  Why not display the CI image, perhaps converting it to a CG image?

Comment: I found that the `MTKView` was not getting clipped, hence the memory error. Metal and AppKit don't really speak to one another. I appreciate the suggestions though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a [suggestion](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651229) from an Apple engineer on the developer forums which was to place an `MTKView` inside the document view of the `NSScrollView`, i.e.:

```c
NSScrollView
  NSClipView
    NSView <-- document view
      MTKView
```

This makes sense since Metal and AppKit don't really talk to one another. With this scheme one can manipulate the document view size to get the scroll bars to reflect correctly and manually set the `MTKView` to be no larger than what is visible in the clip view. Not the ideal solution since there is a lot of NSRect-math involved, but certainly doable. (I haven't had time to implement it yet but will update this answer with any useful information if it comes up.)

The reply on the forum suggested looking at the code that [synchronizes two scroll views](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/SynchroScroll.html) as a good starting point.